# How to get vim to jump to braces in jquery functions in an html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vim

I've got several vim plugins installed and everything seems to be working correctly when editing html files that have jquery.

When I go to a brace, it seems to recognize the corresponding brace, because it highlights it.

The problem is that it doesn't jump to the corresponding brace when I press % like usual.

This becomes a problem when the brace is far away and doesn't fit on the same screen as the enclosing brace.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: What does it do instead?

Comment: *"...when editing html files that have jquery."* That's your problem right there. Don't intermix JS with your HTML (at a source level). It's fine as the result of a build step, but for anything non-trivial, put JS in JS files and HTML in HTML files.